# Plot an eye diagram of a signal in MatLab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, sampling, sample, diagramming

The matrix X contained in a .mat file represents the acquired signal. The element of place (i, j) of the matrix is the i-th sample of the j-th screen. The sampling frequency is equal to 4 GS/s.
How do I plot the eye diagram relative to the signal contained in X using MatLab?
I tried but I could not draw the eye diagram from the matrix X (see http://ge.tt/8Xq5SYh/v/1?c). Here is the link to the matrix X that I used:

http://ge.tt/8Xq5SYh/v/0

and my MatLab code:

```
%sampling frequency fs=4 GS/s
rows=4000;    %4000 rows (samples)    |__ in matrix X
columns=10;   %1000 columns (screens) |

%for plot all the graphics in the same window (overlapping)
hold on;                 

%index of the single row (column for the single column)
row=1:1:100; 

t=1:1:100;
for column=1:columns,
   %plot
   plot(t,X(row, column),'-bo','LineWidth',1, 'MarkerEdgeColor','b', 'MarkerFaceColor','b', 'MarkerSize',2);  
end

%axis properties
set(gca,'YTick', [-0.5 -0.45 -0.4 -0.35 -0.3 -0.25 -0.2 -0.15 -0.1 -0.05 0 0.05 0.1   0.15 0.2 0.25 0.3 0.35 0.4 0.45 0.5]); %soli valori di ascisse da visualizzare
grid on; 
set(gca,'GridLineStyle','-');                                   
axis([0 10 -0.5 0.5]);
```

Someone could try to show me how to do?
maybe the matrix is not correct?

Thanks in advance to anyone who answers

Answer (score 1):

You can simply `plot(x,'b')`. The plot command will draw a line for every column of `x`, which corresponds to all the samples of each "screen". The `'b'` in the command is just to make every line the same color like a typical eye diagram.

Comment: Try `plot(X,'b')` with no loop or anything else. That should look about right. Then you can start modifying appearance however you like.

Comment: I got the same picture of the link above... then I believe that the matrix is not correct...

Comment: what do you think about the matrix X?